# Change width of CKeditor when using class name replacement method

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using `CKeditor` and I use [this](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/replacebyclass.html) method to use it, so I am not binding it directly and hence not sure how to change configuration options without doing it via the config file itself; I have several CKeditor instances throughout the site, so I can't do that.

How can I change the width of it on the fly using the method I am?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - documentation for [Setting CKEditor configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) is very helpful. It describes all standard way of doing that.

So, you can either specify configuration when calling [`CKEDITOR.replace`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) (or other creators like [`inline`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) or [`appendTo`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-appendTo)) or in the config file. These are the standard ways.

There are however more ways which exist thanks to CKEditor's event based architecture. One of them is used in the [Massive inline editing](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/inlineall.html) sample.

```
// The "instanceCreated" event is fired for every editor instance created.
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( evt ) {
    var editor = event.editor;

    // You can choose how each editor should be configured based on
    // any criterias you want, like e.g. its name.
    if ( editor.name == 'foo' ) {
        // Customize the editor configurations on "configLoaded" event,
        // which is fired after the configuration file loading and
        // execution. This makes it possible to change the
        // configurations before the editor initialization takes place.
        editor.on( 'configLoaded', function() {
            editor.config.height = 500;
        } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: How do I get the instance name?

Comment: It's based on the textarea/element `id` or `name` attribute or if it wasn't provided, then it's `editor<num++>`.

Comment: Well as I said I'm not creating the instances directly so I guess I would need to use `editor<num++>`? All I'm doing is including the .js file and then getting it to replace all textareas with the `ckeditor` class.

Comment: Do they (`textarea`s I assume) have ids/names? If yes, then those ids/names will be used by editor. If you have problems with identifying editors, then just add unique ids to your `textarea`s.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. So would I just use the id of the element as the instance name?